# Not able to create AKS with role assignment write for subnet and ACR registry in Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, subscription, azure-aks

I am trying to create Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) with earlier created virtual network (VN) and container registry (ACR).
I am facing below errors.
[image: AKS creation issue]

My user id does not have sufficient permissions to perform this action. Only with basic network settings and no ACR binding, I can create AKS cluster.
Which role, at Active Directory (AD) level and at subscription level, should my user id be having to create this AKS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any permissions on Azure AD level for this to work, but you need `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permissions on the adequate scopes to be able to assign permissions. A built-in role of `Owner` grants that. Otherwise - create a custom role and assign that to your user.